# Is there a measurable set $A$ such that $m(A \cap B) = \frac12 m(B)$ for every open set $B$?

Tags: measure-theory

Is there a measurable set $A$ such that $m(A \cap B)= \frac12 m(B)$ for every open set $B$?

**Edit:** (t.b.) See also [A Lebesgue measure question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89424/a-lebesgue-measure-question) for further answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: [Lebesgue density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem).

Alternatively, approximate $A\cap[0,1]$ with a finite union of intervals.

---

On second thought, those hints are overly complicated.  You can use the definition of Lebesgue measure to find an open set $B$ containing $A\cap[0,1]$ with measure close to that of $A\cap[0,1]$.

Comment: thanks Jonas, but I quickly looked up Lebesgue density theorem but wasnt sure how to apply it.

as your other suggestion. i know m(A ∩ [0,1])=1/2, im not sure what you are trying to say by approximate it with finite union of intervals

Comment: For Lebesgue density, think about what it says for the intersection of $A$ with small intervals.  For the second hint, for every set of finite measure $E$ (here $E=A\cap[0,1]$) and every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite union of intervals $U$ such that the measure of the symmetric difference of $E$ and $U$ is less than $\varepsilon$.