# On one property of the Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exist a set $E\subset [0,1]$ with $m(E)<1$ such that $m(E\cap I)\geq m(I)/2$ for all measurable sets $I\subset [0,1]$? I am not able to construct one, but it seems possible. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is $I$ an interval or an arbitrary measurable subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Duplicate of [A Lebesgue measure question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89424/a-lebesgue-measure-question) - the question is different, but the answers address this question (after taking complements).

Comment: @Jacob. $I$ is an arbitrary measurable subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Nate. I am not sure I see how the answers address this question. What do you mean by taking complements?

Comment: @Nate: I too fail to see how the linked question contains an answer for the present one.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: The "general fact" in xen's answer, applied to $E^c$ instead of $E$, and with, say, $c=3/4$, shows that there is an interval $I$ with $m(E^c \cap I) \ge \frac{3}{4} m(I)$, which means $m(E \cap I) \le \frac{1}{4} m(I)$.  Of course if $I$ is allowed to be any measurable set, this becomes trivial as in Martin Argerami's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such set cannot exist.

Since $m(E)<1$, $m(E^c)>0$. Then $m(E\cap E^c)=0<m(E^c)/2$.